# Best way to ignore empty arrays in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, excel, pandas

I am concatenating values from the cells range into arrays, and if I have an empty value I need to ignore this array and continue with another.
What is the best approach?
That's what I have so far (converted arrs to str because it didn't let me operate with empty values in cells).

```
def get_names_and_probs(row, col, col1, col2):
    prob_array = []
    name_array = str(df.iloc[row, col]).replace(" ","").split(",")
    name_array1 = str(df.iloc[row, col1]).replace(" ","").split(",")
    name_array3 = str(df.iloc[row, col2]).replace(" ","").split(",")
    C = np.array([[i.value for i in j] for j in ws['O1':'Q1']]).ravel()
    С = list(C)
    print(C)

    for k in range(len(name_array)):
        prob_array.append(C[0])
    for k in range(len(name_array1)):
        prob_array.append(C[1])
    for k in range(len(name_array2)):
        prob_array.append(C[2])
    print(prob_array)

get_names_and_probs(0, 14, 15, 16)
```

In my Excel I have columns with the heads as probabilities and cells containing values and corresponding to these probabilities. It looks like:

```
  0 50             30     1
  1 Oval, Round           Irregular
  2 Circumscribed       
  3 High density          Equal density, Low density    
  4 Coarse or “popcorn-like”
```

Such as, [1][50] contains both Oval and Round, [1][30] is empty, and [1][1] is Irregular.
What I'm trying to do is to get an array from each row and then if cell contains more than 1 value append it to array and then associate it with probability above.
In this case, it should look like `name_arr = ['Oval', 'Round', 'Irregular']` and corresponding probabilities should be `[50, 50, 1]` (ignore 30 because of empty cell).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using a counter loop like `for i in range(len(my_list)):` is usually considered unPythonic, and in most cases can be replaced directly as `for item in my_list:`. Your case is strange since you're not using the loop variable at all - you're just appending the *same object* however many times. Is that what you want to do? If you want to put all of `name_array` into `prob_array`, you could do `prob_array.extend(name_array)`. Also, you probably don't need do to `C = list(C)`, you could just do `C[0,0]` instead of `C[0]` and etc, or if you really want, `C = np.array(...).ravel().flat`.

Comment: More directly relevant to your question, the best and easiest way to check for an empty array, list or other collection is `if my_collection:`, but you often don't need to check, since iterating over it (or calling a function that does, like `other_list.extend(my_collection)`) will just be a noop in the empty case.